# How to Update a Collection rows data

Tags: laravel

I want to get the logic how I can update the array data with array. I Have tried the code below but when I update it update the rows with the same data not update as `pid` ordered.

I have my  Edit form Request looks like this

```
array:8 [▼
    "_token" => "6YdueIejLzorveQnzEaG8Fx5eYH9Lk1qcL1LQXya"
    "supplierName" => "DAR ERICA 3"
    "receiptNumber" => "5555KK"
    "truckNumber" => "T 500 FGT"
    "driverName" => "JOHN EMMA"
    "remark" => "OK"
    "pid" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "2"
        1 => "1"
    ]
    "qty" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "100"
        1 => "100"
    ]
]
```

Controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $inv_no)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    // dd($data);

    foreach ($request->pid as $i => $dt) {
        $match = Stock::where('inv_no', '=', $inv_no)->get();
        $match->update([
            'pid' => $request->pid[$i],
            'qty' => $request->qty[$i],
            'inv_no' => $request->inv_no,
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'supplierName' => $request->supplierName,
            'receiptNumber' => $request->receiptNumber,
            'truckNumber' => $request->truckNumber,
            'driverName' => $request->driverName,
            'remark' => $request->remark,
        ]);

        return $this->index();
    }
}
```

Stock table
[image]

So I want to update `id` [7,8] with that `inv_no=GRN2504200001`. How can I do on my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your controller as below.

```
public function update(Request $request, $inv_no)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    // dd($data);

    $stocks = Stock::where('inv_no', $inv_no)->get();
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($stocks as $stock) {  
        Stock::where('inv_no', $inv_no)
            ->where('id', $stock->id)
            ->update([
                'pid' => $request->pid[$i],
                'qty' => $request->qty[$i],
                'inv_no' => $request->inv_no,
                'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
                'supplierName' => $request->supplierName,
                'receiptNumber' => $request->receiptNumber,
                'truckNumber' => $request->truckNumber,
                'driverName' => $request->driverName,
                'remark' => $request->remark,
            ]);

            $i++;
    }

    return $this->index();
}
```

Comment: you code is works, but you can not able to update the new `pid` if you selected from `<option>` tag?, so lets allow user to able to update the `pid` as well

Comment: I understand that code should update `pid` as well, so `'pid' => $request->pid[$i],` added to my code.

Comment: it will not update the `pid` because, we have this condition `->where('pid', $request->pid[$i])`,,, we suppose to check the `id` column and `inv_no` to update other  column,, you can see the table above

Comment: WOW, GREAT , THANK YOU  @Seven it works, But can you explain why are you using `i=0` and `$i++`??

Comment: hey @Seven, kindly can you Explain why using `$=0`

Comment: @Emma you have to specify which element of array `$request->pid` will be used. That is why code should have a variable `$i`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in this way

```
$stockAll = Stock::where('inv_no','=',$inv_no)->get();

foreach($stockAll as $stock){

    foreach($request->pid as $i => $dt){

         $stockData = Stock::find($stock->id);

         $stockData->pid = $request->pid[$i];
         $stockData->qty = $request->qty[$i];
         $stockData->inv_no = $request->inv_no;
         $stockData->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
         $stockData->supplierName = $request->supplierName;
         $stockData->receiptNumber = $request->receiptNumber;
         $stockData->truckNumber = $request->truckNumber;
         $stockData->driverName = $request->driverName;
         $stockData->remark = $request->remark;

         $stockData->save();

    }
}
```

Comment: when you `dd($stockAll) we get all rows with this `inv_no` very well , but when we dd($stockData) we find only one row `first row` and update than one row very well only, instead  two rows need to update

Comment: result of `dd(stockAll)`  `  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => App\Stock {#410 ▶}
    1 => App\Stock {#411 ▶}
  ]
}`

but it update only `0 => App\Stock {#410 ▶}`

Comment: It's a loop. when `$j=0` then update the first row and second when `$j=1` it's update second row.

Comment: your right but this `$stockData = Stock::find($stockAll[$j]->id);` it takes one array and update ruther than `$j=0` and `$j=1`

Comment: Update my code @EmmaMfinanga. And try it now. I tried in my local. It works fine.

Comment: i tried @A.A Noman, it work for one row the socond row does not change,, you can check on my local if you want the real things , emma4082@gmail.com